# SonarQube TF vNext build failing

Tags: c#, sonarqube, tfs-2015

Currently, I have configured Sonar build using TFS vNext build for sonar analysis in TFS 2015.I have used C# 5.1 plugin and Sonarqube 4.5.6 LTS version. 
When build is triggered, I am getting following error:

Could not find a file on the SonarQube server.

http: // server name/static /csharp /SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip
Failed to update the SonarQube MS Build Runner binaries. Check the server url , verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1. Unexpected exit code received from batch file:1

Note: C# plugin was reinstalled but still facing the same issue.
Please help!

Comment: Does C# plugin displayed correctly in "Update Center\Installed Plugins" if you check from Web UI?

Comment: Yes  C# plugin dispayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure you have configured the right settings of SonarQube Server. Details you can refer the introduction from MSDN: [Build Tasks for SonarQube Analysis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/)

Just as the error mentioned, also restart sonar server, after reinstalled C# plug-in.

And make sure the version of MSBuild runner meet the compatible. More info check this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/28/quickstart-analyzing-net-projects-with-sonarqube-msbuild-or-visual-studio-online-and-third-party-analyzers-stylecop-resharper/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But all settings have been done properly as mentioned in the blog.Also, I have restarted Sonar server after reinstalling C# plugin but still same error. Also, pre-processing is successful when done using command line while when done using Visual studio TF vNext build it is failing with the above error.

Comment: After some research, we found that there is some communication problem between Build server and SonarQube server and some change in configuration of Sonar server is needed but we did not find what exact change needs to be done in configuration.Kindly let me know at earliest if anyone has the solution using above hint.

Please help !